# Linkbutton href url

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, linkbutton

I have a loop in my code with dynamic linkbuttons and I want to set the OnClientClick property to open up the link in a new browser window. It sounds simple but I am having a bit of trouble getting it to work.

```
lbUrl = new LinkButton();
lbUrl.Text = r["Url"].ToString();

// r["Url"] is Datarow
lbUrl.OnClientClick = "location.href=" + r["Url"].ToString();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you .ToString in the end is redundant

Comment: Your code changes the page displayed at the same window, try @Curt's answer, or try this, to open URL at same page : lbUrl.OnClientClick = "location.href='" + r["Url"].ToString() + "'";

Answer (score 3):

[`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) will open the link in a new browser tab/window

```
lbUrl.OnClientClick = String.Format("window.open('{0}')", r["Url"]);
```

Ensure your URL is an [Absolute URL](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/design/relative_and_absolute_urls.php3)

Comment: I am getting a Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'www' is undefined. The url is www.google.co.uk

Comment: @nickgowdy `www.google.co.uk` is not an absolute url. Try `http://www.google.co.uk`.